# Day current time for function using excel vba

Tags: excel, datetime, time, vba

searched on Google I found one. Is it possible to format time in [h]:mm format using VBA?

```
Dim currentTime As Date
currentTime = TimeOfDay
```

I passed `currentTime` into database when I dumped data - showing put put as `00.00.00.000000`
not understood why its showing different? Is there any other function to call current time `00.00 AM/PM`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To format the current time to your specs try

```
MsgBox Format(Now(), "hh:mm AMPM")
```